# Pandas: Remove all characters before a specific character in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

how can I remove all characters before a specific character in a Dataframe column? In this example remove everything BEFORE the first comma (,) and of course the companies names will always be of varying length and rarely the same but always before the first comma.

My Dataframe:

```
    address
0   My Company Ltd, address, city, state, postcode, country
1   Business Plc, address, city, state, postcode, country
2   Work Harder Inc, address, city, state, postcode, country
3   Company Business People, address, city, state, postcode, country
```

Desired outcome:

```
    address
0   address, city, state, postcode, country
1   address, city, state, postcode, country
2   address, city, state, postcode, country
3   address, city, state, postcode, country
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.replace`:

```py
df["address"] = df["address"].str.replace(r'^[^,]*,\s*', '')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iry2UO/1) showing that the logic is working.

Comment: I'm a little confused at this, would someone suggest a solution to this?

col1, col2, col3
1
2
3